# Inconsistent state behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component, with roughly the following code in it, and I'm getting inconsistent behaviour. Whenever the button is pressed, state is reset back to [] and is logged as such. However, afterwards whenever foo is called, state is returned to being however it was as if the resetState call had never happened.

Though I can't really include it in the minimal reproducable code, pressing a key calls an api, which returns data to be pushed to the front of the state array

```js
function myComponent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
  }, [state]);

  function foo(data) {
    setState([data, ...temp]);
  }

  function resetState() {
    setState([]);
  }

  window.onload = function () {
      if (event.key === "r") {
          foo([1]);
      }
  }
  return <button onClick={() => resetState()} />;
}
```

Comment: temp and state are both pointing to the same instance of array in memory.  You need to pass a new array to the setState. Clone the array with .map or with `let temp = [...state]` or anyhow else. Same story about any other non-value type data, like Objects, Maps, Sets, etc. And please, read the basic [docs](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) about updating arrays state in React.

Comment: that fixed the issue of it not rerendering when it was supposed to, however the key issue of the state not persisting is still occuring. Is clearing the array with `setState([])` an improper method? I don't understand how on one render  it will print the empty array, but on the next render it is populated as if nothing happened

Comment: If you can elaborate a bit and extend the code, with explanation about how to reproduce the issue and expected behaviour - we would be able to help more. Expecially about "when foo is called" - you dont have this call in your code snippet so I have no idea about how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have added more code - please let me know if any more is necessary to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can guess that this is just a classic `closure` issue. If event listener is attached once during initial component render - it will capture the function you provided in it, i.e. `foo`. And your `foo` function exists on initial component render and it sees and uses initial `state`. But it does not see the next state after `setState` is called, so `myComponent` is called again for a rerender after state change, but `foo` that was attached on previous `myComponent` call exists in the scope of when it was initially attached as a listener. It does not see any updates after that.

To bypass that - just use `functional update`.

```
function foo(data) {
  setState(curr => [data, ...curr]);
}
```

And ensure that you are attaching an event listener in a normal way, and not reattaching it on each component rerender, i.e.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.onload = function () {
      if (event.key === "r") {
          foo([1]);
      }
  }

  return () => {
    ... cleanup code here, to remove event listener
  }
 }, [])
```